# Чекбоксы на странице компонентов в inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

Как сделать три чекбокса на странице компонентов, которые будут работать синхронно. То есть ставишь галочку на любом чекбоксе и на двух других тоже ставятся галочки. и Наоборот при снятии с одного из чекбоксов снимаешь галочку и с двух других галочки снимаются автоматически.

Comment: А зачем их тогда три-то надо?

Comment: Каждый чекбокс будет устанавливать свой компонент. На странице же их конечно больше. Но нужно что-бы именно эти три либо выбраны были одновременно или наоборот не выбраны.

Comment: Придумайте общее название для этих компонентов и объедините их в один чекбокс. Не? Другой вариант: написать pascal-скрипт на обработку нажатий на эти чекбоксы. Но первый вариант проще и быстрее.